# AWS Aurora Postgres Cluster Extremely High Unbillable I/O on Writer Node

Tags: aws-aurora

Exactly at 10pm MDT I upgraded the Aurora Postgres Cluster from 11.14 to 11.15
I may have overlooked a database backup still running during that process. Here are the results:

[image]

I then decided at 5pm same day to fail over to the other node thinking it might clear something but the behavior continued unabated on the new writer node.
Here are more pictures
[image]

and
[image]

and
[image]

and
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're right, my question is what to do about it. I kind of thought that it would be a riddle as it is since it makes no sense to have total write i/o that high and billable is zero. Not that I want to pay for it but why is it the way it is? It started suddenly, no deployments, nothing.

Comment: Is it still showing this level of I/O? Still unbillable? What did AWS support say?

Comment: Didn't contact AWS since it means 7% of $48000 and it's at this point only a nuisance. I had to disable the IOPS alarm.